# How to sort array by value keeping the keys in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I can't figure out why asort isn't working. Neither does any other sort work. $hs['hs_type'] are values that come from MySQL query.

```
$results = $query->result_array();
$hs_types = array();
foreach($results as $hs) {
    $hs_types[$hs['hs_type']]++;
}

$projects = array();
foreach($hs_types as $hs) {
    array_push($projects, $hs);
}
asort($projects);
```

var_dump for my array before sort: array (size=15)

```
  * 8 => int 1709
  * 13 => int 26
  * 7 => int 474
  * 14 => int 800
  * 11 => int 282
  * 6 => int 61
  * 5 => int 23
  * 15 => int 181
  * 3 => int 2
  * 19 => int 3
  * 9 => int 50
  * 1 => int 44
  * 2 => int 2
  * 4 => int 4
  * 18 => int 13
```

var_dump for my array after sort: array (size=15)

```
  * 8 => int 2
  * 12 => int 2
  * 9 => int 3
  * 13 => int 4
  * 14 => int 13
  * 6 => int 23
  * 1 => int 26
  * 11 => int 44
  * 10 => int 50
  * 5 => int 61
  * 7 => int 181
  * 4 => int 282
  * 2 => int 474
  * 3 => int 800
  * 0 => int 1709
```

What I wanted:

```
  * 3 => int 2
  * 2 => int 2
  * 19 => int 3
  * 4 => int 4
  * 18 => int 13
  * 5 => int 23
  * 13 => int 26
  * 1 => int 44
  * 9 => int 50
  * 15 => int 181
  * 11 => int 282
  * 7 => int 474
  * 14 => int 800
  * 8 => int 1709
```

Comment: Show your sort code as well please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are getting everything into your nicely keyed array, then pushing each item into the $projects array (losing the key) then doing a asort on the $projects array.

It shows up with this minor test script:-

```
<?php

$hs_types = array(8 =>  1709,
   13 =>  26,
   7 =>  474,
   14 =>  800,
   11 =>  282,
   6 =>  61,
   5 =>  23,
   15 =>  181,
   3 =>  2,
   19 =>  3,
   9 =>  50,
   1 =>  44,
   2 =>  2,
   4 =>  4,
   18 =>  13);

Echo "\r\nOriginal array\r\n";
print_r($hs_types);

$projects = array();
foreach($hs_types as $hs) 
{
    array_push($projects, $hs);
}

asort($projects);

Echo "\r\nPushed array sorted\r\n";
print_r($projects);

asort($hs_types);

Echo "\r\nOriginal array sorted\r\n";
print_r($hs_types);

?>
```

but it looks like it would be easier to just get the sorted list in SQL in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using your array with asort() and it worked perfectly, coming back with the result you expected:

```
<?php
//your array
$a = array(
    8 =>  1709,
    13 =>  26,
    7 =>  474,
    14 =>  800,
    11 =>  282,
    6 =>  61,
    5 =>  23,
    15 =>  181,
    3 =>  2,
    19 =>  3,
    9 =>  50,
    1 =>  44,
    2 =>  2,
    4 =>  4,
    18 =>  13
);

//print unsorted array
print_r($a);

//sort the array
asort($a);

//print the sorted array
echo "<br/><br/>";
print_r($a);
```

If this really isn't working for you, why not do the sorting in the SQL query instead? Then you wouldn't need to bother re-sorting it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using `asort` instead of `sort` ? I tried your code and it works perfectly :

```
<?php 

$myArray = array(
    8 => 1709,
    13 => 26,
    7 => 474,
    14 => 800,
    11 => 282,
    6 => 61,
    5 => 23,
    15 => 181,
    3 => 2,
    19 => 3,
    9 => 50,
    1 => 44,
    2 => 2,
    4 => 4,
    18 => 13,
);

var_dump($myArray);

asort($myArray);
var_dump($myArray);
?>
```

My result :

[image]